# for loop fails with sequence of iterables containing decimals less than one

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

It's a compound issue. First, my `for-loop` gives an error **"Error in datalist[[i]] <- x : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex"** when inputting a sequence of iterables containing values < 1. Second, when setting the sequence of iterables to contain values >= 1, only the largest value is taken from that range. When I check to see with a sequence of iterables containing values > 1, the for loop works fine.

```
# Example data 
df <- data.frame(variable = rep(letters[1:4],3),
             SteadyState = sample(0:1,12,replace = T),
             measurement = sample(0:20,12))

# Range containing values less than 1
range_less_than_1 <- seq(0.25,0.75,length.out = 4) # Throws error message

# Range containing values  >= 1
range_greater_than_1 <- seq(1,1.75,length.out = 4) # Only 1.75 operates

# Range containing values > 1
range_much_greater_than_1 <- seq(2,20,length.out = 4) # Works fine

datalist <- list()
for (i in range_less_than_1){
  x <- df %>% 
    group_by(variable)%>% 
summarise(`Range (<)`=i,
          TP = length(which(measurement <= i & SteadyState == 1)),
          FP = length(which(measurement <= i & SteadyState == 0)),
          FN = length(which(measurement > i & SteadyState == 1)),
          TN = length(which(measurement > i & SteadyState == 0)))
datalist[[i]] = x
}
df_2 = do.call(rbind,datalist)
```

Desired output:

```
seq(0.25,1.75, length.out=5)
# [1] 0.250 0.625 1.000 1.375 1.750
```

```
> df_2
# A tibble: 16 x 6
   variable `Range (<)`    TP    FP    FN    TN
   <fct>          <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 a               0.25     0     1     2     0
 2 b               0.25     0     0     3     0
 3 c               0.25     1     0     1     1
 4 d               0.25     0     0     2     1
 5 a              0.625     1     1     1     0
 6 b              0.625     1     0     2     0
 7 c              0.625     2     0     0     1
 8 d              0.625     0     0     2     1
 9 a                 1      2     1     0     0
10 b                 1      2     0     1     0
11 c                 1      2     0     0     1
12 d                 1      0     1     2     0
13 a              1.375     2     1     0     0
14 b              1.375     3     0     0     0
15 c              1.375     2     1     0     0
16 d              1.375     2     1     0     0
17 a              1.750     0     1     2     0
18 b              1.750     0     0     3     0
19 c              1.750     0     0     2     1
20 d              1.750     0     0     2     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
datalist <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(range_less_than_1)){
      x <- df %>% 
      group_by(variable)%>% 
      summarise(`Range (<)`= range_less_than_1[i],
              TP = length(which(measurement <= range_less_than_1[i] & SteadyState == 1)),
              FP = length(which(measurement <= range_less_than_1[i] & SteadyState == 0)),
              FN = length(which(measurement > range_less_than_1[i] & SteadyState == 1)),
              TN = length(which(measurement > range_less_than_1[i] & SteadyState == 0)))
  datalist[[i]] = x
}

> df_2 = do.call(rbind,datalist)
> df_2
# A tibble: 16 x 6
   variable `Range (<)`    TP    FP    FN    TN
   <fct>          <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 a              0.25      0     1     0     2
 2 b              0.25      0     0     1     2
 3 c              0.25      0     0     2     1
 4 d              0.25      0     0     1     2
 5 a              0.417     0     1     0     2
 6 b              0.417     0     0     1     2
 7 c              0.417     0     0     2     1
 8 d              0.417     0     0     1     2
 9 a              0.583     0     1     0     2
10 b              0.583     0     0     1     2
11 c              0.583     0     0     2     1
12 d              0.583     0     0     1     2
13 a              0.75      0     1     0     2
14 b              0.75      0     0     1     2
15 c              0.75      0     0     2     1
16 d              0.75      0     0     1     2
```

Comment: Hi Rushabh, it didn't work. I need to retain the values of `i` as the decimals. Using `length()` just returns the number of items in that range, not the actual values.

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm! What's the logic behind having to code `range_less_than_1[i]`?

Comment: You are calling `ith`  element of `range_less_than_1` sequence/vector.